# Google Admin SDK API - HttpError 412 "Domain user limit reached. Contact Support."

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-admin-sdk

I want to perform a load test of a python script which creates users in the GoogleWorkspace. The purpose of the load test is to confirm that 100 users can be created successfully using "Google_add.py".However, I faced the following Error.

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 412 when requesting https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?alt=json returned "Domain user limit reached. Contact Support.">

**the load test I did and the result**

①To create 50users →OK

②To create 100users →only the first 10 users were successfully created, and the others raised the above HttpError.

**My license**

Google Workspace Business Starter
In my recognition, up to 300users can be created by this lisence.

**Questions**

①What is "Domain user limit"?

②How can I avoid this error?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits#api-limits-and-quotas   10 users pee minute maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I remember that I had this error before, reviewing the documentation from Google [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/support/directory_api_common_errors#412limitexceeded), I found this information.

##### Note: It makes reference to an API for resellers, on our case since we do not have access to use the reseller API it's best to contact support.

> This error occurs when your customer has reached their maximum seat
> limit. To resolve this issue, Use the subscriptions.changeSeats method
> and depending on their subscription plan, use the following:
>
> For `FLEXIBLE`, increase the `maximumNumberOfSeats` parameter.
> For `ANNUAL`, increase the `numberOfSeats` parameter.

If the issue is actually the number of seats you can actually [contact Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213), and they can increase the number for you. Is a very simple process, and that one worked for me with this error.

However, if you are 100% sure that you didn’t reach the `Maximum number of seats`, you might have reached a quota limit for the `Directory API`.

> You cannot create more than 10 users per domain per second using the Directory API.

You can solved that issue by implementing [Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits#backoff).

As an extra advice, be careful when testing the creation of users in Google Workspace. When I was getting that error I kept testing by deleting users and creating new ones and I reached a different error message `A request for user account creation is disallowed as we've detected some potentially abusive behavior. Please contact Google support for help.`

For that error it is best to [contact support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213), explain that you are running some tests of creation of users, and if they can remove the ban for you.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check my maximum Number Of Seats.